# All the ID in Reference object in the ViewModel is 0 while Post method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, razor

I Have a viewmodel which consist of a Object that is retrieved from the Entity framework. I am using that view model in the Razor View to display the required fields. While trying to update that object , I am getting errors because all the IDs in the reference object inside that Object are set as 0.

I have went through few solutions where it was mentioned to set hidden field with the ID property.

```
<input type="hidden" value="@Model.TID" />
```

But I have to set almost 20 hidden fields in this above solution.

So, can you please help me to guide a standard way of binding this ID property for the object and the Objects inside that object.

Model Description

```
[Table("Country")]
public class Country : BaseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int TenantId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(450)]
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int CurrencyId { get; set; }
    public int Region7Id { get; set; }
    public int? Region8Id { get; set; }
    public int? Region9Id { get; set; }
    public int? Region10Id { get; set; }

    public int Approach { get; set; }
    
    public bool AggregatedOnEntrepreneurTrPartner { get; set; }

    public bool IsRegionalBms { get; set; }

    public int? Region11Id { get; set; }
    public int? Region12Id { get; set; }
    public int? Region13Id { get; set; }
    public int? Region14Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsTemplate { get; set; }
    public int? CountryTemplateId { get; set; 

    #region ForeignKeys
    [ForeignKey("TenantId")]
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CurrencyId")]
    public virtual Currency Currency { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Region7Id")]
    public virtual Region Region7 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Region8Id")]
    public virtual Region Region8 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Region9Id")]
    public virtual Region Region9 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Region10Id")]
    public virtual Region Region10 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Region11Id")]
    public virtual Region Region11 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Region12Id")]
    public virtual Region Region12 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Region13Id")]
    public virtual Region Region13 { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Region14Id")]
    public virtual Region Region14 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CTmpId")]
    public virtual Country ConTemplate { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GxxpLocalId")]
    public virtual Gxxp GxxpLocal { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("GxxpGroupId")]
    public virtual Gxxp GxxpGroup { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: "I have to set almost 20 hidden fields in this above solution" Whether you are update a list of objects or not? Can you share the related class definition, so that we could give some suggestion based on the model.

Comment: @ZhiLv I have added the model description to add some more details